# How to use CSS Top with it's parent element, rather than it's value relative to the document

Tags: html, css

I'm making a single page website for a friend and I'm currently working on the about age. I have this design idea to have square `divs` to be layered on top of one another using different `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` values. But whenever I set the `top` or `bottom` values, their new position is relative to the entire document, rather than it's immediate parent div (`.about-container`). How can I make sure that the square divs and their `top`/`bottom` values are relative to their parent container, rather than the entire document?

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

div {
 display: block;
}

nav ul, nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit; 
}

#body {
 visibility: visible;
 max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

#desktop-navbar {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1;
}

#desktop-logo{
 float: left;
}

.logo {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
} 

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 height: 90px;
 padding: 0 45px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 35px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper, #mobile-nav-wrapper, #mobile-menu-link {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#home {
 height: 700px;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FzFVTMR/Whats-App-Image-2019-03-06-at-13-56-45.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-content {
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#about {
 height: 700px;
 background-color: #c96567;
}

.about-container {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 height: inherit;
}

#about-div-one {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red;
 left: 25%;
  top: 35%;
}

#about-div-two {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 left: 75%; 
  top: 64%;
}

#about-div-three {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: orange;
 left: 74%; 
 top: 65%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="home">
     <div id="home-content" class="container">
      <p>tatuando. dibujo. pintura. estilo de vida.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
  
   <div id="about">
  <div id="about-div-one" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-two" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-three" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top: The effect of top depends on how the element is positioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that `position:absolute` positions a `div` depending on the next positioned (i.e. not static) ancestor - and because there are no non-static ancestors, it automatically defaults to position it based on the body.

If you want your three elements to be positioned based on the parent, the recommended course of action would be to assign a `position:relative` to the immediate parent (which would be the div with and `id` of `about` rather than `.about-container` (which is simply the class assigned to your three divs).

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

div {
 display: block;
}

nav ul, nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit; 
}

#body {
 visibility: visible;
 max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

#desktop-navbar {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1;
}

#desktop-logo{
 float: left;
}

.logo {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
} 

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 height: 90px;
 padding: 0 45px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 35px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper, #mobile-nav-wrapper, #mobile-menu-link {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#home {
 height: 700px;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FzFVTMR/Whats-App-Image-2019-03-06-at-13-56-45.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-content {
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#about {
 height: 700px;
 background-color: #c96567;
    position:relative;
}

.about-container {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 height: inherit;
}

#about-div-one {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red;
 left: 25%;
  top: 35%;
}

#about-div-two {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 left: 75%; 
  top: 64%;
}

#about-div-three {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: orange;
 left: 74%; 
 top: 65%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="home">
     <div id="home-content" class="container">
      <p>tatuando. dibujo. pintura. estilo de vida.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
  
   <div id="about">
  <div id="about-div-one" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-two" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-three" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `relative position` on `#about` to make elements in `#about` in `absolute` position, `relative` to `#about` and not the document.

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

div {
 display: block;
}

nav ul, nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit; 
}

#body {
 visibility: visible;
 max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

#desktop-navbar {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1;
}

#desktop-logo{
 float: left;
}

.logo {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
} 

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 height: 90px;
 padding: 0 45px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 35px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper, #mobile-nav-wrapper, #mobile-menu-link {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#home {
 height: 700px;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FzFVTMR/Whats-App-Image-2019-03-06-at-13-56-45.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-content {
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#about {
 height: 700px;
 background-color: #c96567;
    position: relative;
}

.about-container {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 height: inherit;
}

#about-div-one {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red;
 left: 25%;
  top: 35%;
}

#about-div-two {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 left: 75%; 
  top: 64%;
}

#about-div-three {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: orange;
 left: 74%; 
 top: 65%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="home">
     <div id="home-content" class="container">
      <p>tatuando. dibujo. pintura. estilo de vida.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
  
   <div id="about">
  <div id="about-div-one" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-two" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
  <div id="about-div-three" class="about-container">
   
  </div>
 </div>
```